# Smallest symmetric table containing all subsets of $[2n]$

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients, extremal-combinatorics

Inspired by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4104424/smallest-table-containing-all-subsets-of-2n/) question.

Consider the set $[2n]=\{1,2,\dots,2n\}$ for some positive integer $n$. Let $A_1,\dots,A_k$ be subsets of $[2n]$ such that every subset of $[2n]$ is equal to $A_i\cup A_j$ for some $i,j$. What is the minimal $k$ possible?

A first bound is $k^2≥4^n$, so $k≥2^n$. Actually more since $k(k+1)/2\ge 4^n$.

Notice that combining all $a$-subsets with all $b$-subsets, where $b\ge a$, you obtain all the $c$-subsets where $b\le c \le a+b$, so an upper bound would be
$k\le 1 + \binom{2n}{1}+\binom{2n}{3}+\binom{2n}{7}+\dots$
choosing $A_i$ all subsets of cardinality $0,1,3,7,\dots,2^m-1$.

Comment: Peace. How did you get $k(k+1)/2\ge 4^n$?

Comment: the number of different unions $A_i\cup A_j$ is at most $k(k+1)/2$ since $A_i\cup A_j = A_j\cup A_i$

Comment: The same construction works as for the previous answer, which gets you within a factor of $2$ of the lower bound.

Comment: The minimum values of $k$ for $n=1,2,3$ are $3,7,15$.

Comment: The minimum value for $n=4$ is in $[25,31]$.  Starting to look like $2^{n+1}-1$.